# Self-hosting ruby lobste.rs app, how to create tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have followed instructions at [Lobste.rs github README](https://github.com/jcs/lobsters), as well as some other sources, and successfully got a Lobsters instance running using Apache, MySQL, Passenger, and RVM Ruby on a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS.

I was hoping to use this Lobsters instance as a private bookmark collection (I plan to hide the site behind some form of auth later).

The Lobsters instance is up and running - it is reachable at `mylobster.example.com`, and I can log in with the administrator account created during setup.

During setup, the command `rake db:seed` initialised the database with a single tag "test". This tag is accessible from "Submit story" in the web UI, as expected.

But how do I create new tags? With some variation of the rake command above and a list of pre-defined tags? Or can it be done via the web UI somehow?

Answer (score 1):

In the Rails console, run Tag.create(tag: "hello", description: "example tag", is_media: false).

Here are the tag attributes in schema.rb

```
# Tag attributes
# t.string  "tag",         limit: 25,  default: "",    null: false
# t.string  "description", limit: 100
# t.boolean "privileged",              default: false
# t.boolean "is_media",                default: false
# t.boolean "inactive",                default: false
# t.float   "hotness_mod", limit: 24,  default: 0.0
```

Here's a portion of a sample seed file with all of them:

```
Tag.create(tag: "ask", description: "ask tag")
Tag.create(tag: "inactive", description: "inactive tag", inactive: true)
Tag.create(tag: "media", description: "media tag", is_media: true)
Tag.create(tag: "meta", description: "meta tag")
Tag.create(tag: "negative hotness", description: "negative hotness tag", hotness_mod: -1)
Tag.create(tag: "privileged", description: "privileged tag", privileged: true)
Tag.create(tag: "positive hotness", description: "positive hotness tag", hotness_mod: 1)
Tag.create(tag: "show", description: "show tag")
Tag.create(tag: "test", description: "test tag")
```

And here's what they appear as in the app:

[screenshot of the tags above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrL9e.png)

The green backgrounds for the ask and show tags come courtesy of @pushcx with some simple css in app/assets/stylesheets/local/yourappname.css

```
a.tag_ask, a.tag_show {
  background-color: #34a713;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}
```

For reference [original post](https://github.com/jcs/lobsters/issues/319)